# Maven - два приложения с одним общим модулем

Tags: java, maven, модули

Здравствуйте! В рамках одного проекта, есть два приложения (модуля), которые используют один общий модуль. Перевожу все это дело на maven и столкнулся c проблемой, как это все описать там?

> приложение 1
>
> приложение 2
>
> common - общий модуль, который они используют[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект не собирается всецело, а собирается по отдельности каждое приложение, которое при сборке использует общий модуль common. Подскажите, как это дело описать сборщику? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может модуль common просто указать как dependecy? Maven найдет его в локальном репозитории.

Проект common:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.net.arh</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

maven->install

project1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.net.arh</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.net.arh</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Аналогично с project2

Comment: Не могли бы подкинуть пример?

Answer (score 1):

надо сделать общий модуль или общего родителя в мавене

Comment: т.е. необходимо у каждого из приложений указать parent - common?
А как тогда собирать приложения? Приложения должны собираться от parent, разве нет?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсвем ваш случай, но думаю это вам поможет:

приведу технику, которая позволит включать в 2 разных мавен проекта - один общий модуль, лежащий исходниками в третьем каталоге. Суть проблемы кторая тут решается - это то, что сам модуль не знает куда его включают, и его помник не содержит завязки на проекты, в которых он участвует.

Общий модуль надо описать с помощью простого POM. Ни разу не группового и т.д. Как будто он сам по себе. Это 1-й pom.xml.

Далее, создаете 2-й pom.xml, это групповой проект; и в нем указываете ваш общий модуль (1-й pom.xml) в секции `modules`:

```
<modules>
        <module>./path/to/shared/project/pom.xml</module>
</modules>
```

Далее, 3-й pom.xml - это ваш основной проект, в котором вы хотите импортировать 1й модуль. указываете на 2й как на родительский групповой проект в секции `parent`.

После этого, можно добавить в 3-й pom.xml зависимость на ваш "общий" модуль (1-й pom.xml) используя обычный `dependency` тег.

Аналогично для вашего другого приложения. Сначала делаете для него групповой pom.xml, указываете у него в modules на 1й помник; и теперь любой помник, который указывает на этот групповой как на родительский, может импортировать 1й помник обычным `dependency`.

В итоге 1-й помник используется в 2-х проектах, ничего не знает о тех проектах где он используется, и все довольны.

Техника редко используемая, потому мало где описанная, а если верить части популярных руководств по мавену - даже невозможная.